# Is there a command line or some other way to bring up nm-applet UI?

Tags: network-manager

Folks,

Environment: Ubuntu 14.04

In my current environment, nm-applet icon can be seen in the panel (as expected). I can right-click on it and bring up its UI.

I need to trigger the same UI from within my application. Is there a command line tool I can run to bring up this UI? Or, perhaps there is a message I can send to the panel to force-display the UI?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Regards,
Peter

Comment: If you wish to control NetworkManager, the [`nmcli`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/nmcli.1.html) command might be of interest.

Answer (score 2):

You could try "nm-connection-editor". Maybe this package have to be installed (I did not know anymore if I have installed this package later).

Comment: `nm-connection-editor` is provided by the `network-manager-gnome` package (normally already installed).

Comment: @Sylvain Pineau: Thanx